# Getting parameter value from $resource in Angular using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json, wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve data from my Wordpress database using an Angular factory. Using `ng-click="updateCommentsById(v.id.videoId)"` I call the following function:

```
$scope.updateCommentsById = function(id) {
    commentRepository.query(({videoId: id}), function (data) {
        $scope.comments = data;
    });
}
```

That corresponds to the following factory definition:

```
angular.module("app")
    .factory("commentRepository",
        function($resource) {
            return $resource("/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite-child/inc/get_comments.php/:videoId",
            {
                videoId:"@id"
            });
        });
```

The problem is how to get the `videoId` parameter into my PHP function inside `get_comments.php`:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-load.php");
function get_comments_by_id($id)
{
    echo $id;
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        echo json_encode("Not Authorised");
    } else {
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM analyser_posts WHERE video_id = $id", OBJECT);
        echo wp_json_encode($result);
    }
}
get_comments_by_id(videoId);
```

### EDIT:

Turns out the get_results() method doesn't allow variables inside SQL statements, I should use prepare() (safer anyway) instead. I also changed the request URL. The new code becomes:

```
angular.module("app")
    .factory("commentRepository",
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource("/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite-child/inc/get_comments.php?video_id=:videoId");
        });
```

and PHP:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-load.php");
function get_comments_by_id($id)
{
    var_dump($id);
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        echo json_encode("Not Authorised");
    } else {
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM analyser_posts WHERE video_id = $id", OBJECT);
        var_dump($result);
        $result_array = array();
        if($result){
            foreach($result_array as $r){
                $result_array[] = $r;
            }
        }
        var_dump($result_array);
        echo json_encode($result_array);
    }
}
get_comments_by_id($_GET["video_id"]);
```

However the var_dumps show that the id gets passed correctly, only the prepare() doesn't actually execute anything. Should I wrap that in a get_results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work using the answers (including those now removed) and comments. The function inside my Angular controller code:

```
$scope.updateCommentsById = function(id) {
    commentRepository.query(({videoId: id}), function (data) {
        $scope.comments = data;
    });
}
```

Repository:

```
angular.module("app")
    .factory("commentRepository",
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource("/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite-child/inc/get_comments.php?video_id=:videoId");
        });
```

get_comments.php:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-load.php");
function get_comments_by_id($id)
{
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        echo json_encode("Not Authorised");
    } else {
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `analyser_posts` WHERE `video_id` = '$id'", OBJECT);
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
get_comments_by_id($_GET["video_id"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extract it from the URI:

```
//$args is an array of every part separated by `/` (ignoring the query string)
$args = explode('/',strtok(trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/'),'?'));

//the last element is the video id
$video_id = end($args);
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/LChIc)

Comment: The query returns an empty array. Could it be because it adds the colon required in the `$request` call?

Comment: Was the video ID captured successfully? what do you see if you `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `var_dump($video_id)` ?

Comment: When I add a var_dump the controller function no longer accepts the response ([error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object&p3=GET&p4=%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fzerif-lite-child%2Finc%2Fget_comments.php%3Fvideo_idVGY0A0asgu8))

Comment: @SjorsHijgenaar That makes sense. You'll need to enter the target URL directly in the browser address bar to see the response. This is how you can test what your server is sending the controller.

Comment: I see. I did what you said, allowing me to see the var_dumps. I will edit the question, I can tell I'm nearly there.

Comment: @SjorsHijgenaar This is now a different question. The initial question was how to pass the video ID to PHP.  As for this new problem, using `prepare` by itself doesn't actually execute the query. I don't have any experience with WordPress or its interface for making queries (all my prepared queries are native `mysqli` queries) so I suggest you look into how to execute prepared statements in this context. If you can't figure it out, open a new question with just that code

Comment: You're right @BeetleJuice, the question changed, but should anyone come looking I have added my own answer that features working code.